# TexSoup for Bib-Files

Tags: python, linux, tex, bibtex, latex-suite

this is my first question so I will try to do everything as proper as possible.

I am currently using LaTeX to write my documents at my University because I want to use the powerful citing capabilities provided by BibTeX. For ease of use, I am writing on scripts that will implement my .bib-files into my .tex files easier and allow easier management of my .bib-files. As I am using Arch Linux, I did this in bash, but it is a little clunky. Therefore I wanted to switch to python, as I came across the TexSoup-library for Python.

My issue is now, that I cannot find resources regarding the use of TexSoup for .bib files, I can only find resources on .tex-files. Does anybody know, if and if yes how I can use TeXSoup to find books / articles or other entries in my bib-files with python (or the TexSoup-library)?

```py
with open("bib_complete.bib") as f:
    soup = TexSoup(f)

print(soup)
```

This is a code sample I am trying to use, but I don't know how to look for entry names or entry-types with the package. I would really appreciate if someone could guide me to good resources if they exist.
I hope my writing was comprehensive enough and not too long.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Just to get some context: what do you want your scripts to do with the bib files?

Comment: I want them to go through the bib files and e.g. check for duplicates in entry-names, make new entries or very basically just print out one specific entry between a pair of {} brackets. If there is an easier way than the TexSoup-libary, that would be fine too

Comment: To insert bib keys into your document, I would use an editor which already provides such functions, e.g. texstudio. To check for duplicates, there are many existing scripts, e.g. https://code.google.com/archive/p/bibtex-check/downloads or https://github.com/pezmc/biblatex-check

Comment: ... and finally to manage your bib file, there many bibliography tools, jabref, mendeley, ... They make it easy to create new entries.

Comment: might also be relevant: http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~charnik/oss/bibtool/#downloads

Comment: Tank you very much, I will check out those resources.